# Modulecatalog.Modules is empty with DirectoryModuleCatalog normal behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

**Problem:**

If I use the *DirectoryModuleCatalog*, then the *ModuleCatalog* keeps empty, only after *base.InitializeModules();* the modules are in the *ModuleCatalog*, but already initialized.

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
  var moduleCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
  return moduleCatalog;
}

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        // No Modules are in the list
        // I aspect, that temp shall not empty, temp shall have the modules in the list of my directory, of the module shall not be initialized. 
        var temp = ModuleCatalog.Modules;
        base.InitializeModules();
        // Modules visible but already init done
    }
```

If I add the modules by code to the ModuleCatalog, then of course my list is not empty

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            Type module1Type = typeof(ModuleHelper);
            string path = module1Type.Assembly.Location;
            IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = new ModuleCatalog();
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(
                  new Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo()
                  {
                      ModuleName = module1Type.Name,
                      ModuleType = module1Type.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                      Ref = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri
                  });

        }

 protected override void InitializeModules()
        {
            // temp is not empty 
// Modules visible and init not done
            var temp = ModuleCatalog.Modules;

            base.InitializeModules();

        }
```

**Question:**

Should the modules not in the list be, after the
    DirectoryModuleCatalog has been instantiated? Is this the normal
    behavior for the DirectoryModuleCatalog?

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem as a result of this behavior? Is something broken?

Comment: I mean is a bug or I misunderstand the DirectoryModuleCatalog. Hope somebody confirm the bug or correct my understanding.I would like to use the DirectoryModuleCatalog to show available Modules, but before they are initialized and this seems not possible with this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves exactly as expected.  The Prism DirectoryModuleCatalog class allows you to specify a local directory as a module catalog in WPF. This module catalog will scan the specified folder and search for assemblies that define the modules for your application. To use this approach, you will need to use declarative attributes on your module classes to specify the module name and any dependencies that they have.